# Java Rest API - Method to return balance on account

Tags: java, rest

I need to get the balance for a particular customer id and account id.

I have these two java classes. ( both classes have their get and set methods )

**Customer**

```
public class Customer {
private int custid;
private String name;
private String address;
private String email;
private int pin;
private List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();


public Customer(){ 
}

public Customer(int custid,String name, String address, String email, int pin, List<Account> accounts) {
    this.custid = custid;
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.email = email;
    this.pin = pin;
    this.accounts = accounts;
}
```

**Account**

```
public class Account {
private int accid;
private int sortCode;
private int accNumber;
private String accType;
private double currentBalance;   
private List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<>();

public Account(){
}

public Account(int accid,int sortCode, int accNumber, String accType, double currentBalance, List<Transaction> transactions) {
    this.accid = accid;
    this.sortCode = sortCode;
    this.accNumber = accNumber;
    this.accType = accType;
    this.currentBalance = currentBalance;
    this.transactions = transactions;

}
```

I have these two Customer service and Account service classes.
Here is a method that is inside the CustomerService and Account Service

**CustomerService**

```
public Customer getCustomer(int id) {
    return cList.get(id-1);
}
```

**AccountService**

```
public Account getAccount(int accid) {
    return aList.get(accid-1);
}
```

I need to take two parameters in my get request like so. I have the below in a separate class.

```
@GET
@Path("/{customerID}/{accountID}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Customer getBalance(@PathParam("customerID") int cID,@PathParam("accountID") int aID ) {
    //gets customer for CustomerServices and returns it
return customerService.getCustomer(cID);
}
```

How can I return the balance on given *customer* id and their *account* id?

Comment: Look into DTOs. You can send anything back in your response. Based on cID and accontID you can create a custom response object that would contain the customer details and the account balance. Another approach would be to add customer mapping into Account entity - which will get you an Accountz+Customer object based on cID and accountID but not sure if this suits your business logic

Comment: I have `//Get specific customer from customers using id
        Customer c = customerService.getCustomer(cid);
        //Get a list of the accounts on that customer
        List<Account> accounts = c.getAccounts();
        //Return the specific account from the array of accounts
 return accounts.get(aid-1);` 
which returns the account but I want return only the balance. How do I reflect that?

Comment: Thats where DTOs come in. Create a class for e.g. CustomerResponse that has all the fields of the Customer class and an additional field for the balance. Pass in the all the values and return that DTO(Custom class). But again if you add Customer mapping into the Account class then you get the specific account Account acc = repo.getAccount(aid) and acc.getCustomer() will get you the customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@GET
@Path("/{customerID}/{accountID}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getBalance(@PathParam("customerID") int cid, @PathParam("accountID") int aid) {
    //Get specific customer from customers using id
    Customer c = customerService.getCustomer(cid);
    //Get a list of the accounts on that customer
    List<Account> accounts = c.getAccounts();
    Account a = accounts.get(aid - 1);

    Double newBalance = a.getCurrentBalance();
    return "Balance for Customer ID " + cid + " with account ID " + aid + " is " + newBalance;

}
```

That's my answer in case anyone is looking at this post and needs something similar.